# Tkinter: How do I hide text as if with a password with a Text (not Entry) widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I know with an `Entry` widget, in Tkinter, you can do this:

```
Entry.config(show="*")
```

and it will show asterisks instead of whatever you type.

However, I would like to do the same thing with a `Text` widget, but there is no `show` option to configure for `Text` widgets. Is there any way to do this in a `Text` widget? It'll mean a lot less work for me if there is.

The reason it will be less work is because I have lots of custom functionality and customizations set up for my `Text` widget class, and I don't want to have to reprogram it all over again for an `Entry` widget, when a one-line Text widget works just fine in its place (other than maybe this feature). `Text` and `Entry` widgets have different ways to access indexes and such, and these are quite involved. My customizations make it so you can do such as press `ctrl+left` to skip back a word, and all kinds of stuff like that (and complicated stuff not like that, too, which may or may not have to do with indexes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the text widget has no such feature. You would have to implement it yourself, and I'm guessing it would be very difficult to make it work.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm thinking about just using a wingding font for it or something. I don't know anyone who can actually read those. Or, I could use a font that has things that look like asterisks for every character. Or, I could just make the font size really small and unreadable. Or, I could make the background and foreground very close to each other.